# Grouping by overall score based on a range of values and a score table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given a big table of data about when people begin and complete tasks, e.g:

```
Person  |  Task | Date started | Date ended
---------------------------------------------
A        Cleaning  20-FEB-2012  22-FEB-2012
N        Dishes    20-FEB-2012  24-FEB-2012
Z        Cleaning  21-FEB-2012  23-FEB-2012
```

and a score table which assigns scores of 2,3,4 for each task based on how long it takes them to do it, e.g.:

```
|  Task | Days taken | Score
---------------------------
Cleaning      2        2
Cleaning      1.5      3
Cleaning      1        4
Dishes        3        2
Dishes        2.5      3
Dishes        2        4
```

how might I produce a query which gives the overall score for each person for each task, e.g.:

```
Person  |  Task | Overall Score
---------------------------------------------
A        Cleaning  3.1
A        Dishes    2.7
N        Cleaning  3.4
```

The solution's been subtly eluding me, some assistance would be appreciated! I'm using SQLite at present.

Comment: Dont you have a FK in the first table that mentions the Task ID !

Comment: No, the person who designed the database that I'm working with usually treats string values such as the values for Task as his FKs rather than actual IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definitions are a bit vague.  However, the following should help you:

```
select t.person, t.task, sum(s.score)
from tasks t left outer join
     score s
     on t.task = s.task and
        s.daysTaken = t.julianday(dateended) - t.julianday(datestarted)
group by t.person, t.task
```

Handling ranges a bit more difficult.  You need to get the two ends of the interval, and then do the join:

```
select t.person, t.task, sum(s.score)
from tasks t left outer join
     (select s.*,
             (select min(days_taken) from score s2 where s2.person = s.person and s2.task = s.task and s2.days_taken > s.days_taken
             ) as nextDays_Taken
      from score s
     ) s
     on t.task = s.task and
        t.julianday(dateended) - t.julianday(datestarted) >= s.days_taken and
        t.julianday(dateended) - t.julianday(datestarted) < nextDays_Taken
group by t.person, t.task
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. I've realised that there's another facet to the problem though - the scores are actually ranges, i.e. <1 days for Cleaning task is a score of 4, 1<days<2 is a score of 3, and >2 days is a score of 2. I can't see how I can perform joins when s.daysTaken doesn't fall directly on 1,1.5,2.